# Apple app store:- Upload and submit app for third party

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, provisioning-profile, ios-provisioning

My client added me as a team in his apple developer account and he wants me to upload app on his behalf.

Have I to create certificate and provisioning profile from my account?
How will I be able to submit app on his account?

Note:- This is not for testing purpose. 
Can anyone help me out.

Comment: you are the team member or teamadmin?

Comment: @PoojaSrivastava team member

Comment: team meber is not allow to upload the app on app store please be sure you are the upload the app team admin or team agent only.

Comment: Not allowed for members only admin can create it, after it you can upload version to testFlight and min can submit it to store.

Comment: Ok suppose I have team admit rights.. then all the certificates and provisioining of his account would be accessible at my end ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Please make sure you are the **Team Admin** or **Team Agent**. Through Apple document [About Apple Developer Program Team Roles and Privileges](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/ManagingYourTeam/ManagingYourTeam.html)

Team Roles

**Team Agent**-
A team agent is legally responsible for the team and acts as the initial primary contact with Apple. The team agent can invite team members and change the access level of any other team member. There’s only one team agent.

**Team admin**-
A team admin can set the privilege levels of other team members, except the team agent. Team admins manage all assets used to sign your apps, either during development or when your team is ready to distribute an app. Team admins can edit the App ID to enable app services and create technology specific identifiers used throughout the system. Team admins can sign apps for distribution on nondevelopment devices.

**Team member**-
A team member can create their development certificate, register a device connected to their Mac, and create a team provisioning profile using Xcode. Team members can’t register devices and create development provisioning profiles using their developer account.

Comment: yes @MayankJain  sure please see the rule of team admin. apple says if you are the `Team admins manage all assets used to sign your apps, either during development or when your team is ready to distribute an app.`

Comment: Thanks a lot.. let me check

Answer (score 3):

In case your client has everything set up, he would need to share his production certificate in .p12 format (exportable via Keychain) and his already created production provisioning profile.

Otherwise you could create everything by yourself by logging into his account.

Comment: He shared the p12 certificate... but I will need the provisioining profile too

Comment: Yes, that's what I said, he can share an existing one with you or you can create it in the developer portal under your client account.